# What wrecked ship was found near Lyttelton, New Zealand in 1847?

Tags: ships, new-zealand

I am currently reading *The Strange Adventures of Captain Quinton.* It tells the story of a young man who goes to sea, rising in rank to Captain.  Captain Quinton wrote the book in 1912 as a memoir of his travels and adventures.

Early on, he describes a stop in Lyttelton, New Zealand. In passing, he notes that a wrecked ship was found there in 1847.

Quote:

> It is interesting in this connection to note that in 1847 the hulk of an ancient ship was found 650 feet inland from the village of Lyttelton, and far above the high-water mark.

I know that Quinton wasn't any kind of historian - in just the few pages I've read I've found discrepancies in place names and other things.  Still, he doesn't seem to be making things up.  It's more that he misremembers things.  For example, he says that Pinchgut Island was renamed to Fort Donelson when in fact it was renamed to Fort Denison.

What ship might have been found in about 1847 near Lyttelton, New Zealand? How old was the hulk, and where could I read more about it? Did Quinton hear a tale of another ship or another location that he might have incorrectly placed at Lyttelton?

I have not had any success in my searches.  I can find lots of information about shipwrecks or about Lyttelton, and even shipwrecks near Lyttelton, but I can't find anything about "an ancient hulk" found near Lyttelton in 1847.

Comment: Does Lyttelton have an archaeological society? If the site was found 650 ft inland, there's a chance it was explored/excavated. "Ancient" in this case could mean anything from just older than living memory to hundreds/thousands of years.

Comment: @SteveBird:  Thank you for the suggestion.  I found some sites for historical societies and archeology in Lyttelton and New Zealand.  I'll have a closer look at them later.

Comment: [The New Zealand Pilot, 1875](https://archive.org/details/thenewzealandpilot/page/n234/mode/1up), quotes a letter by the harbour's custom collector from 1855: "The harbour has proved, as regards all winds from seaward, perfectly safe; the severest and most trying gales blow down the harbour from S. W., and though with only a fetch of four miles, and a portion of that over shoal ground, it sends quite a heavy sea on the beach at Lyttelton, on which two vessels have been wrecked from anchoring within the points of the bay, where the holding is not good."

Comment: Equally, the WP article about Lyttelton cites two newspaper articles from 1851 ([June 14th](https://paperspast.natlib.govt.nz/newspapers/LT18510614.2.6), [July 5th](https://paperspast.natlib.govt.nz/newspapers/LT18510705.2.9)) about severe storms that threw several ships onto the shore. Even if none of these were the one Quinton mentioned, isn't it possible that a ship "found" inland of the high water mark was actually found to be thrown that high up after a storm gale? Especially since it could not have been found 1847 "inland from the village", the settlement being founded only in 1848/49.

Comment: He's on a ship "shuttling" between Newcastle and Port Chalmers, I wonder why they spent 6 weeks at Lyttelton? I can't see any records of boats inland at either Lyttelton or PC, other than possibly small waka.